# Issue with rotating a UIimageview

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, rotation

I'm having a bit of an issue rotating an image in x code, What I'm trying to do is to get an image to spin infinitely about its center point, however there is a weird issue when I try this.

This is the code I'm using:
Viewcontroller.h:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
IBOutlet UIImageView *RotateTest;
NSTimer *TimerTest;
float angle;
}
-(void)Spintest;
@end
```

Viewcontroller.m:

```
-(void)Spintest{
RotateTest.transform = (CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle));
angle += 0.05;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
TimerTest = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.02 target:self selector:@selector(Spintest) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

However when I run this code, I get this issue:
[Youtube video showing the issue](http://youtu.be/FimRqzL8Keo)

Before you post anything really complicated, I don't know too much about x code / objective-c so please go easy on me if I don't understand something.

Thanks

Update: I've tried this solution with no luck either:

```
RotateTest.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(RotateTest.transform, angle);
angle = 0.05;
```

along with adding:

```
RotateTest.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5,0.5);
```

Update 2: I've tried doing this on a uibutton just out of interest and that yielded no results either, Does anyone have any ideas?

Note: This is using a storyboard and the image is linked up correctly.

Note2: I've searched on google and cant find much info, it seems like a really trivial question, doesn't anyone have an answer?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but take a look at `CGAffineTransformRotate()` instead of storing the angle in the view controller.

Comment: not related to your problem, but instead of a timer you really should use a `CADisplayLink` if you do stuff like this. I guess the problem you see is because of the anchorpoint (check CALayer anchorPoint documentation)